# Looping over .csv file and removing any non-ascii strings

Tags: python, loops

I have a .csv file that contain a large number of emails, each on a separate line. I am trying to remove any emails that contain non-ascii characters. This is what Im trying:

```
def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open('emails.csv') as csv_file:
        for line in csv_file:
            if(is_ascii(line)):
                with open('result.csv', 'a') as output_file:
                    output_file.write(line)
```

It keeps giving me an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 5012: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Is this Python 2, or Python 3?

Comment: it should work if you open the file as binary `open('emails.csv','rb')`

Comment: @Rakesh The data is basically an email on each line. However, some emails obviously have non-ascii characters. For example, ¢¢¢@gmail.com.

Comment: @abarnert Python 3

Comment: As a side note, you can write `is_ascii` as `ord(max(s)) < 128` or `max(s) < '\x80'`. Either way is significantly faster, and a bit shorter—but I'm not sure whether it's more readable, or less, which is probably much more important here. But after switching to bytes, `max(s) < 128` definitely looks better than `all(c < 128 for c in s)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have no idea what the encodings are for non-ASCII emails, so you just want to skip them.

But your code is trying to decode them with your default encoding, and *then* deciding whether to skip them. That's what it means to open a file in text mode, like this:

```
with open('emails.csv') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
```

Since that default encoding is UTF-8, as soon as you run into something encoded in some other charset that isn't UTF-8 compatible, you get an error.

---

The easiest way to change this it to instead is to open the file in binary mode. Then you can decode only the lines you've decided to keep:

```
with open('emails.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        if(is_ascii(line)):
            line = line.decode('ascii')
            with open('result.csv', 'a') as output_file:
                output_file.write(line)
```

… or just stay with bytes the whole way by also opening the output file in binary mode:

```
with open('emails.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        if(is_ascii(line)):
            with open('result.csv', 'ab') as output_file:
                output_file.write(line)
```

Either way, you will have to change your `isascii` function, because a `bytes` is a sequence of integers from 0-255, rather than a sequence of characters, so you can't (and don't need to) call `ord`:

```
def is_ascii(s):
    return all(c < 128 for c in s)
```

---

There is a potential problem. I think you'll be fine, but you should think it through (and test whatever you need to test). While text-mode file objects automatically handle non-Unix newlines, binary-mode files do not.

If you somehow have classic Mac (pre-OS X) files from the previous century, with `\r` endings, your code will not work. The `\r` won't be treated as a newline at all, so the whole file will look like one huge line. If you don't expect to have any such files, I wouldn't worry about it.

But if the only non-Unix files you have are Windows (or DOS), with `\r\n`, you'll be fine. The `\r` will get treated as part of the line rather than part of the newline, but that won't matter for your code (`ord('\r') < 128`, and beyond that, all you're doing is writing the whole line worth of bytes at once), so things will just work.

Comment: Both these solutions are giving me the same exact error

Comment: @user711 Are you looking at the original, unedited version? I left off the `'rb'` on the `open` calls, which defeated the whole purpose of the change. If you still don't see `'rb'` anywhere, try reloading the page,.